# Why was "What is the biblical definition of marriage" put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34723/what-is-the-biblical-definition-of-marriage

The reason given was that the question was unclear. How is this question unclear?

Answer (score 8):

The five of us who voted to close the question [saw this first](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/34723/1).

There's some pretty obvious problems there. It's not exactly clear what he's asking. There isn't even a question in the body. [Caleb's comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34723/what-is-the-biblical-definition-of-marriage#comment93150_34723) covers it pretty well:

> This questions seems to have two main issues. ① It reads as more of a statement than a question and ② whatever the question is is not fleshed out enough to make it clear what is expected of answers. Without some kind of framework or scope inside Christianity this is likely to be too broad.

Now, it's clear enough, but I have reservations to vote to reopen. The body now asks:

> Can someone direct me to any Scriptures which will define marriage?

"Sure, here's a concordance." He already did that. Really, how useful is a question that asks us to do what a concordance does?

Now you're saying "well he's asking what the Bible says that defines marriage, etc." That's personal interpretation. You might be right. You might be wrong. It doesn't really matter because it is your interpretation, as in, *opinion*.

We just don't do personal interpretation on this site. We haven't for a very long time. Nixing that from allowable topics is what has allowed this site to survive and be an academic place for learning about all the forms of Christianity, instead of just a club of like minded Christians.

Comment: [Related and highly relevant to the last two paragraphs here.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/what-is-wrong-with-answering-general-questions-biblicaly)